# Having a lot of methods in one controller VS having multiple controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an app and I am pondering over something. So I figured I would ask here for people with experience to tell me what they think about it.

So I have this controller (Store controller) which is huge and has a lots of methods, Get and Post actions, and so on in it. It works fine, but I'm still in development stage.

I am wondering what would be the best practice: to have this controller which holds so many methods and actions, or splitting the methods to many controllers? Is it ideal to have one controller deal with almost all of the methods, or many controllers?

And before you ask, yes, everything in my store controller is "store related". But in my store I have items, packages, and so on.

**Edit**

Thanks everyone! Following your advice, I have broken my huge `Store` controller into smaller controllers: one for the Items, one for the Packs, and so on. This indeed made the code more readable. Also, a lot of comments provided will put me on track for upgrade, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

It is definitely better to divide all your controller's actions into some logical packages - so to move them to separate controllers. Thanks to this it all becomes much more readable and intuitive for you also for other developers who will work on the project.

The question is: how to divide it?

There are in fact a few criterias that can influence such a decision for e.g.:

- A controller should be connected with a certain set of logically connected pages. So for e.g. in case of an e-commerce platform you would probably have a CheckoutController, ProductController, UserAccountController etc.
- You should also take into account which business concepts should be taken into account. In your case you have a concept Store, but as you are probably aware of this that it is a very broad concept in itself. So instead you should probably distinguish some more details in the business concepts.

A quite common approach is to divide controllers by CRUDs, although it is not always applicable. 
On the other hand your controllers should not be too granulated - so you should not exaggerate with it.

Please remember that ASP.NET MVC uses CoC (Convention over Configuration) approach which is also applicable to controllers and views naming conventions and the way they are grouped and placed in appropriate directories. When dividing your controller you should take this into account.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer multiple controllers than a single controller with many actions. I would do it this way - Let a BaseStoreController derive from Controller, this controller is going to have the common functionality and properties. Then have StorePackageController, StoreItemsController etc be derived from BaseStoreController.

And inside each controller I will have corresponding Actions related to packages, items etc. Inside each action I will make sure I will use Command Pattern and Facade pattern to ensure proper code separation.

Comment: I totally agree.  Single responsibility principle.  I think the controller should just do model binding and dispatching.  I highly recommend Jimmy Bogards MediatR.  In a stateless application what is shared between two endpoints?  Nothing.  So controller would just be coupling things together for organizational reasons only..  And folders can do that better.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a controller per discrete unit you're working with. So, if your controller manages multiple entities, then yes, I'd say it's time to break it out. However, length of the controller, otherwise, makes no difference.

Now, the only problem you'll have using separate controllers is your routes, but that can be easily fixed by either of the following:

1. **Use Areas.** Areas allow you to sort of create a sub-MVC project. It'll give you Controller, Model, and View directories all under a new prefix. So, if you had a controller named `ItemsController` in your `Store` Area, the default route would end up being `Store/Items`. However, C# developers have very mixed feelings regarding Areas: some love them, some hate them with a burning passion.
2. **Use Attribute Routing.** MVC 5 has a new feature called attribute routing. This allows you to specify the route directly on your controller and its actions instead of relying on the default route or adding tons of custom routes to your route config. So, you could then easily have as many controllers as you want and specify that they should all be prefixed with "store" in the URL. As long as there's no conflict in the rest of the URL, you'll be fine. If you aren't working with an MVC 5 project and don't want to upgrade, there's also a Nuget package called AttributeRouting that offers these features (and actually more). For what it's worth, the author of that package is also the author of attribute routing in MVC 5.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way I approach it is to have one controller per menu option

For example, say you have a site with the menu options

Home, Products, Blog, FAQ etc

I would have a HomeController, ProductContsController, BlogController and FAQController

You could also potentially create one or two generic controllers that handle shared actions used by several sections of your website and a base controller than handles generic tasks such as tracking and logging page visits.

One other thing to be aware of is SSL, especially if you decide to do some shared controllers actions or decorate an entire controller (For example shoppingcart etc) with SSL

Comment: Pardon my newbness, but what is SSL?

Comment: SSL - secure socket layer - ie Https. If you want pages on your site to be encrypted - typically pages where you ask the user to enter personal information, for example a store check out page

Comment: Oh yes, that would be very interesting. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It appears from your first post that you are writing a store, ie an eccommerce site. My advice (at a very high level) would be to have controllers per menu option, one controller for your checkout that is HTTPS and a generic controller that contains actions to support footer SEO links on your layout page and menu related actions etc.

Comment: I'm refactoring things to reflect what you are all suggesting because it makes a lot of sense. Next I'll have to make the HTTPS thing. May I ask another thing? By footer SEO links, you mean what exactly?

Comment: Send me a PM and I will message you some details of what I mean without clogging up the board

Comment: Its a time to go [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)!

Answer (score 1):

If your methods are truly "Store" related and bind your model to the View, then that's one thing.  But if some of your "Store" methods are essentially helper classes, that is, methods that don't directly interact with your view but do serve a purpose when working with your Store model, then create a separate "Store" helper class and place this in, for example, a "HelperClasses" folder in your root.  In my opinion, and I'm sure opinions of others, you want to try to only keep methods in your controller that directly tie into the model (the Store model) that your View renders and works with.  This encourages "separation of concerns".  If your Store methods don't do that, send them to a helper class.  Basically - your controller acts as the middle man when rendering your model to the view.  It helps control the process, so every method in your Store controller should really have something to do with how your controller sends your model to the View.  Hope that makes sense.

And as Chris Pratt mentioned, if your controller manages multiple objects, then yes separate them into separate controllers, **OR**, create a `ViewModel` to handle the multiple objects, but from what you said, I don't think this is the case because you mentioned everything in your Store controller is "Store" related.

Answer (score 1):

you might consider using a partial controller and split methods by logical meanings.

```
public partial class StoreController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

in in some other .cs or .vb file:

```
public partial class StoreController
{
    public ActionResult Show()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: A few people suggested this but I don't know what's a partial controller. Could you bring in an example?